# Calculate program execution time

Tags: c, windows

I have a program in C which has to execute a series of another programs. I need to get the execution time of each of these programs, in order to create a log of these times.

I though of using system() to run each program, but I don't know how to get the execution time. Is there any way to do this?

The programs are "quick", so I need more precision than seconds.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least 4 ways to do it.

### (1)

A start point:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>

 int main ( void )
 {
    clock_t start = clock();

    system("Test.exe");

    printf ("%f\n seconds", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
 }
```

### (2)

If you are in Windows and you have access to Window APIs you can use [`GetTickCount()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) too:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <windows.h>


 int main ( void )
 {
    DWORD t1 = GetTickCount();

    system("Test.exe");

    DWORD t2 = GetTickCount();

    printf ("%i\n milisecs", t2-t1);
    return 0;
 }
```

### (3)

And the best is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    LARGE_INTEGER start;
    LARGE_INTEGER end;
    double interval;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    system("calc.exe");

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
    interval = (double) (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;

    printf("%f\n", interval);

    return 0;
}
```

---

### (4)

Question is tagged as `C` but for sake of completeness, I want add `C++11` feature:

```
int main()
{
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  system("calc.exe");

  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto x = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2-t1).count();

  cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: The `clock()` thing shouldn't work. `clock()` is supposed to return the best approximation to the CPU time used by the programme, it shouldn't count the time used by a `system()`-invoked programme (and it doesn't here, may be different on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

```
    start = clock();  // get number of ticks before loop
     /*
      Your Program
    */

    stop  = clock();  // get number of ticks after loop
    duration = ( double ) (stop - start ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```